# Accusativus cum Praedicativo

Tags: accusativus-cum-infinitivo

I've been reading *The Early Latin Verb* by Wolfgang David Cirilo de Melo, where in a footnote he writes:

> Synchronically, the participle here is best analysed as an elliptical perfect passive
> infinitive, although diachronically it is part of an older construction, **the acc. with
> praedicātı̄uum.**

Emphasis mine. The passage to which he refers is this:

> (40) (Eunomia promises to help her son.)
>
> *Scı̄s* tūte *facta uelle* mē quae tū *uelı̄s.* (*Aul.* 686.)
>
> You *know* that I *want* the things *done* that you *want.*

Emphasis his, and not really relevant to this question. I would like to know more about this 'older construction, the acc. with praedicātı̄uum', as he puts it.

I've certainly come across the form that might be parsed as an ellipsis of the infinitive *esse* with adjectives (e.g., *puto eum sontem (esse)*), with past participles (*puto eum amatum (esse)*), with future participles (*puto eum amaturum (esse)*), and with gerundives (*puto eum amandum (esse)*); but de Melo claims that ellipsis is not the only possible mechanism.

So in addition to my broader question, which is just a request for more information generally, I am curious to know whether this *accusativus cum praedicativo* occurs in constructions that cannot easily be parsed as AcI + ellipsis: e.g., with the present participle (*puto eum currentem*).

Comment: I suspect one could always add *esse*, even with present participle. So I'm not sure whether it could be proven that way. But perhaps Cirilo de Melo (is that his last name?) says this because instances with *esse* become less common and even disappear as one goes back in time: that would suggest the ones without *esse* represent the original construction.

Comment: @Cerberus As for your suspicion that "one could always add _esse_, even with present participle", one cannot do it in cases like _video te venientem_ or _facit Laertem agrum colentem_. You cannot add _esse_  there.

Comment: Are you sure that your final sentence _puto eum currentem_ is grammatical in Latin? Cf. ok _Video eum currentem_ // _Tibicinam cantantem audio_, etc. This construction (by the way, without _esse_!; see my comment above) is more typical with perception verbs.